# how much it will take to update og:title for facebbok sharing

Tags: facebook

I studied a lot and came to know that og:title should be visible in facebook shared post. I check my rendered html and its look pretty good. Here it is:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SinePulse" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sinepulse.com/about-us" />
<meta property="og:title" content="About Us" />
<meta property="og:description" content="SinePulse GmbH is a Munich based fast growing company that provides high quality and cost effective solution to industries, corporate clients, governments and NGOs. We have a global platform with active operation in EU, North America and Asia. SinePulse GmbH have almost 300 experts around the world to provide best quality services to our clients. Having a global platform, SinePulse GmbH experts keep on working round the clock for your satisfaction. You just place your idea and we do the rest. We start with requirement engineering and specification preparation." />
```

**view-source:http://www.sinepulse.com/about-us**

But when I explore it at:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

```
<meta property="og:title" content="About Us" />
...
...
<meta property="og:title" content="SinePulse" />  <- this was old html.
```

I am using drupal 7. And the problem is the og: tags have been updated in my live site but I can see the backdated cached html on facebook debug tool.Is it a problem? Will it take time to propagate?

Comment: Shows fine in the debut tool right now. Did you just forget to re-scrape …?

Comment: thank you. Yes it works. what does it mean by  re-scrape?

Comment: The debug tool shows you when this was last scraped, and if that was too long ago (Facebook caches this data), then you click the button next to it to scrape the URL again, to update the cache.